# Swift 4 show / hide keyboard going over view

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I am trying to implement a show / hide on my keyboard, but the problem is when I show my keyboard it goes over my view and more importantly it goes over the my text field and button, so I can type, I just can't push my button.

Here are the screenshots before the keyboard:

[image]

and here is when the keyboard is presented:

[image]

as you can see I can't see the text field and button.

Here is my code in my `viewDidLoad`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CommentsController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CommentsController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

and here are the methods:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
          if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
              self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
          }
     }
 }

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
     if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
          if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
              self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
          }
     }
 }
```

Why is my keyboard going over my view? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`